# why a newline is being created in the below function?

Tags: c, printf

I tried to create an own printf function only for printing  `double`, `int` and character value, here goes the code

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void inta(int ch) {
  int count = 0;
  int num = ch;
  while (ch != 0) {
    ch /= 10;
    count++;
  }
  int t = 0;
  char *s = (char*) calloc((count + 1), (sizeof(char)));
  printf("%s\n", s);
  while (num > 0) {
    s[t] = 48 + (num % 10);
    num /= 10;
    t++;

  }
  s[t] = '\0';
  int len = t - 1;
  for (int a = 0; a < t / 2; a++) {
    char temp = s[a];
    s[a] = s[len];
    s[len] = temp;
    len--;
  }
  for (int a = 0; a < t; a++) {
    putch(s[a]);
  }
}

void floata(double num) {
  int n = (int) num;
  inta(n);
  double rem = num - n;
//printf("rem = %lf\n",rem);
  while (1) {
    if (rem - (int) rem < 0.0001) {
      break;
    } else {
      rem *= 10;
      // printf("rem npw %lf\n",rem);
    }
  }
  putch('.');
  inta(rem);
}

void chara(int ch) {
  putch(ch);
}

void print(const char *str, ...) {
  float p;
  int ch;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, str);
  char *fmt;
  for (fmt = str; *fmt != '\0'; fmt++) {
    while (*fmt != '%') {
      putch(*fmt);

      fmt++;
    }
    fmt++;
    switch (*fmt) {
      case 'c':
        ch = va_arg(ap, int);
        chara(ch);
        break;
      case 'd':
        ch = va_arg(ap, int);
        if (ch < 0) {
          putch('-');
          ch = -ch;
        }
        inta(ch);
        break;
      case 'f':
        p = va_arg(ap, double);
        if (p < 0) {
          putch('-');
          p = -p;
        }
        floata(p);
        break;

    }
  }
  va_end(ap);
}

int main() {
  int q = 119;
  double aa = 12.34;
  int a = 123;
  char b = 'z';
  print("%d   %f  %c", q, aa, b);
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
123 12.34 z
```

but the output is:

```
119
12.
34 z
```

I used `putch` function to print every character, why some newlines is being created?

How to remove this newline>?

Comment: what newline and why '123' when q==119 ?

Comment: You code does not compile. What is `putch`?

Comment: Did you forget the header `conio.h`?

Comment: but it runs without conio.h

Answer (score 2):

> How to remove this newline>?

Remove `printf("%s\n", s);`